# Derivative of a product $P_{x_n}(z) = \prod_{i=1}^n\frac{1+z+z^2 +...+z^{i-1}}{i} $

Tags: combinatorics

If $P_{x_n}(z) = \prod_{i=1}^n\frac{1+z+z^2 +...+z^{i-1}}{i} $

would

i)  $P_{x_n}'(z)=\sum_{i=1}^n(\prod_{j\neq i}\frac{1+z+...+z^{j-1}}{j})(\frac{1+2z+3z^2+...(i-1)z^{i-2}}{i})$

or

ii) $P_{x_n}'(z)=\sum_{i=1}^n(\prod_{j = i}\frac{1+z+...+z^{j-1}}{i})(\frac{1+2z+3z^2+...(i-1)z^{i-2}}{i})$

I'm trying to make sense of my lectures notes, any help would be appreciated.

I have worked it out as i) because using the product rule, the choose term differentiated in the product to be the i'th term, so it would be on the outside of the product, as

$(\frac{1+2z+3z^2+...(i-1)z^{i-2}}{i})$

but his notes (copied from a blackboard) state ii), maybe I made a mistake while copying?

Comment: Of course the answer is i). You know, we always make some typos when writing on blackboard.

Comment: Dude, thank you so much. I know right - the qualms of being a student :D