# Is there some way to simplify $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j\neq i}(\frac{j-1}{2})(\frac{i-1}{2}) $ To obtain a closed form.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation

Is there some way to simplify $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j\neq i}(\frac{j-1}{2})(\frac{i-1}{2}) $?

Does it have a closed form? It's the last piece of a puzzle I need to solve a similar question [Differentiate $P_{x_n}(z) = \prod_{i=1}^n\frac{1+z+z^2+...+z^{i-1}}{i}$ twice to calculate the variance of involutions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/722701/differentiate-p-x-nz-prod-i-1n-frac1zz2-zi-1i-twice-to)

Taking the example

$\sum_{i=1}^4 \sum_{j\neq i}(\frac{j-1}{2})(\frac{i-1}{2}) = (\frac{2-1}{2} + \frac{3-1}{2} + \frac{4-1}{2})(\frac{1-1}{2}) + (\frac{1-1}{2} + \frac{3-1}{2} + \frac{4-1}{2})(\frac{2-1}{2}) + (\frac{1-1}{2} + \frac{2-1}{2} + \frac{4-1}{2})(\frac{3-1}{2}) + (\frac{1-1}{2} + \frac{2-1}{2} + \frac{3-1}{2})(\frac{4-1}{2}) = 2(\frac{1-1}{2}\frac{2-1}{2})+ 2(\frac{1-1}{2}\frac{3-1}{2}) + 2(\frac{1-1}{2}\frac{4-1}{2}) + 2(\frac{2-1}{2}\frac{3-1}{2}) + 2(\frac{2-1}{2}\frac{4-1}{2}) + 2(\frac{3-1}{2}\frac{4-1}{2})$

I feel that since the sums are decreasing in number by one with regard to $\frac{i-1}{2}$ there should be a factorial term in the closed form, I'm just not sure how to obtain it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the range for the $j$ in the sum? All numbers different from $i$, or all numbers different from $i$ between $1$ and $n$?

Comment: @ABC: Have you read the example?

Comment: all numbers different from $i$, between $1$ and $n$

Comment: @user2345215 I read it and I know the answer.

Comment: Consider $(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i-1}{2})(\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{j-1}{2})$. Notice the sums insider the brackets can be computed in closed form. Only the terms $\frac{(i-1)^2}{4}$ (when you open the brackets) are not in your sum. But those can be summed in closed form too.

Comment: so would that then be $(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i-1}{2})(\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{j-1}{2}) - \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(i-1)^2}{4}$?

Comment: And then afterwards find the closed forms for $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i-1}{2}$ and for $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(i-1)^2}{4}$. Do you know how?

Comment: Follow @ABC then see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula

Comment: Is it fixed now? also, $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i-1}{2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{4}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(i-1)^2}{4} = \frac{1}{4}(\frac{(n-1)(n)(2(n-1)+1)}{6})$?

Comment: $\sum _{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{4} \left( i-1 \right) ^{2}=\sum _{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{4}{j}
^{2}=\frac{1}{24}n \left( 2\,n-1
 \right)  \left( n-1 \right) $ I think you have an extra "1" in the bracket on the right...

Comment: $2(n-1)+1=2n-1$ it's the same

Comment: @Henry so it is :)

Answer (score 4):

To answer my own question,

$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j\neq i}(\frac{j-1}{2})(\frac{i-1}{2}) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n(\frac{j-1}{2})(\frac{i-1}{2}) - \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(i-1)^2}{4} $

Which simplifies to

$\frac{n(n-1)}{4}\frac{n(n-1)}{4} - \frac{1}{4}(\frac{(n-1)n(2(n-1)+1)}{6})$

or just $\frac{(n - 2) (n - 1) n (3 n - 1)}{48}$